# launchctl gives "Invalid property list" error, but plutil validates "OK"

Tags: launchd, plist, xml

```
mariano@host LaunchAgents % plutil local.test.plist 
local.test.plist: OK
```

But then:

```
mariano@host LaunchAgents % sudo launchctl load local.test.plist
Password:
/Users/mariano/Library/LaunchAgents/local.test.plist: Invalid property list
```

File in question:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
                <key>Label</key>
                <string>local.test.plist</string>
                <key>ProgramArguments</key>
                <array>
                <string>/bin/echo</string>
                <key>"Hello world"</key>
                </array>
                <key>StartInterval</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, the issue with your plist is that you have "Hello world" in `<key>` tags instead of `<string>` tags. While this is technically valid xml, it is not a valid plist, and certainly not a valid launchd configuration plist.

#### Invalid

```plist
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
    <string>/bin/echo</string>
    <key>"Hello world"</key>
    </array>
```

#### Valid

```plist
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/echo</string>
        <string>"Hello world"</string>
    </array>
```

You can actually have `plutil` fix this by using

```bash
plutil -convert xml1 local.test.plist
```

By default, the `plutil` command uses the `-lint` option by default if no other options are specified

From man plutil(1):

```
 - lint         Check the named property list files for syntax errors.  This is the default command option if none is specified.
```

My assumption is that this lint feature is not 100% fully baked and can miss some edge cases like this. It is likely just checking for matching opening and closing tags, but not the context of the keys and/or where they are.

Even though the documentation is getting a bit out of date these days, [launchd.info](https://www.launchd.info/) is a great resource for launchd configuration and management. [This this blog post](https://babodee.wordpress.com/2016/04/09/launchctl-2-0-syntax/) has some great information about the more recent commands used to manage launchd.

Comment: Thank you so much @n8felton! Your reply is **perfect** for me to understand the concept, find my mistake and fix it. Also thank you so much for the recommendation for -convert option! I will surely make use of this every time I work with launchd, this is fantastic advice! Thanks again!

Comment: Hello @n8felton ! I don't think I can yet accept answers. I have to little points, so I cannot even upvote answers. Unless I'm missing something. Cheers.